# TSQL catch some tricky condition (example is here)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this task to catch ONLY ProcID=11 based on 2 conditions:
1. it has mirrored change (i.e   'Base -> Mirror* -> Base'  AND
2. this change happened on the SAME day (2015-1-10 in my example).

And here i'm kinda struggle, probably it's end of the day. Will appreciate your feedback. Here is the sample with test data. My solution alas is just a draft. I need get rid of ProcID=333.
Bset
Mario

```
  SELECT * INTO #T FROM (        -- drop table #T
SELECT 11 ProcID, '2015-1-10' DD, 'Base to Mirror!!!' TransVal , 'Yes!' flag UNION  -- like '%Base%to%Mirror%'
SELECT 11 ProcID, '2015-1-10' DD, 'Mirror!!! to Base' TransVal, 'Yes!' flag UNION
SELECT 11 ProcID, '2015-1-15' DD, 'Base to Bravo300' TransVal, '' flag UNION
SELECT 11 ProcID, '2015-1-3' DD, 'Approved' TransVal, '' flag UNION
SELECT 333 ProcID, '2015-1-18' DD, 'Base to Mirror_DiffDD' TransVal, '' flag UNION
SELECT 333 ProcID, '2015-1-19' DD, 'Mirror_DiffDD to Base' TransVal, '' flag UNION
SELECT 44 ProcID, '2015-2-20' DD, 'Initiated' TransVal, '' flag UNION
SELECT 44 ProcID, '2015-2-21' DD, 'Base to Mirror200' TransVal, '' flag  ) g

SELECT ProcID, MAX(DD) LastDD, MAX(Flag) Flag,
( SELECT COUNT(*) cc FROM #T t2 WHERE t2.ProcId = t1.ProcID AND
             (TransVal LIKE '%Base%to%Mirror%' OR TransVal LIKE '%Mirror%to%Base%') ) AS C1
--            GROUP BY DD) AS C1
FROM #T t1
WHERE 1=1 
AND TransVal LIKE '%Base%to%Mirror%' or TransVal LIKE '%Mirror%to%Base%'
AND EXISTS  (
    SELECT 1 FROM #T t2 
    JOIN  #t t3  ON t3.ProcId = t2.ProcID   AND t3.TransVal LIKE '%Mirror%to%Base%'
    WHERE t2.ProcID =  t1.ProcID
          AND t2.TransVal LIKE '%Base%to%Mirror%'
        )
GROUP BY procID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Would it not be as simple as replacing Where 1=1 with WHERE ProcID=11

Comment: Tx, John, 11 is used for sample, I need to bring this on stated 2 conditions, Sorry did you put some bad points to my post?

Comment: I think this will cover the SAME DAY requirement HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 and Min(DD)=Max(DD)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I've over-simplified it, but this seems to produce the desired results.

```
Select ProcID
      ,LastDD  = max(DD)
      ,Flag    = max(Flag)
      ,C1      = count(*)
 From  #T
 Where TransVal Like '%Base%to%Mirror%' or TransVal LIKE '%Mirror%to%Base%'
 Group By ProcID
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 and Min(DD)=Max(DD)
```

Returns

```
ProcID  LastDD      Flag    C1
11      2015-1-10   Yes!    2
```